# Set facebook application web.config settings in code (C#)

Tags: c#, facebook, web-config, settings

I'm trying to set the web.config settings in a facebook app from code to avoid working directly with the web.config file. 
I've tried a custom ConfigurationSection class, and then using the WebConfigurationManager to reach the web.config file. The problem is that I can't get an instance of the Configuration object. This is my code:

```
public class FacebookConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
[ConfigurationProperty("appId")]
public string AppID
{
    get { return (string)base["appId"]; }
    set { base["appId"] = value; }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("appSecret")]
public string AppSecret
{
    get { return (string)base["appSecret"]; }
    set { base["appSecret"] = value; }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("canvasPage")]
public string CanvasPage
{
    get { return (string)base["canvasPage"]; }
    set { base["canvasPage"] = value; }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("canvasUrl")]
public string CanvasUrl
{
    get { return (string)base["canvasUrl"]; }
    set { base["canvasUrl"] = value; }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("cancelUrlPath")]
public string CancelUrlPath
{
    get { return (string)base["cancelUrlPath"]; }
    set { base["cancelUrlPath"] = value; }
}

public FacebookConfigurationSection()
{
}

}
```

And the page that uses this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

    FacebookConfigurationSection _config = new FacebookConfigurationSection(); 
    _config = config.GetSection("facebookSettings") as FacebookConfigurationSection;

    //FacebookConfigurationSection config = (FacebookConfigurationSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        _config.AppID = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
        _config.AppSecret = TextBox2.Text.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text))
        _config.CanvasPage = TextBox3.Text.ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text))
        _config.CanvasUrl = TextBox4.Text.ToString();

    _config.CancelUrlPath = "";
    config.Save();
}
```

The web.config looks like this (the part I'm trying to work with):

```
<configSections>
    <section type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection, Facebook" name="facebookSettings" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</configSections>

<facebookSettings
  appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  appSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  canvasPage = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  canvasUrl ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  cancelUrlPath = "" />
```

Doing this, gives me the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on _config, which tells me that nothing gets returned.

Is there anything "facebook specific" that causes this?

Another thing; I came across this new method of working with facebook settings in code:

```
FacebookContext.SetApplication( IFacebookApplication )
```

I haven't been able to find a good example that uses this.
Has anyone worked with this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find any good examples on using

```
FacebookContext.SetApplication( IFacebookApplication )
```

and I'm not sure it's even possible to do it the "ConfigurationSection" way...

So, I cheated..

I loaded the web.config file into an XmlDocument object and manipulated it that way...

```
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("web.config"));

    XmlAttribute appId = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//facebookSettings//@appId") as XmlAttribute;
    if (appId != null) appId.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

    XmlAttribute appSecret = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//facebookSettings//@appSecret") as XmlAttribute;
    if (appSecret != null) appSecret.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();

    XmlAttribute canvasPage = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//facebookSettings//@canvasPage") as XmlAttribute;
    if (canvasPage != null) canvasPage.Value = TextBox3.Text.ToString();

    XmlAttribute canvasUrl = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//configuration//facebookSettings//@canvasUrl") as XmlAttribute;
    if (canvasUrl != null) canvasUrl.Value = TextBox4.Text.ToString();

    XmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("web.config"));
```

It works, and in my solution, it's ok...

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
var sec = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings"); 

FacebookConfigurationSection config = (sec as Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection);
```

config.AppID etc etc

Comment: you can format you code by selecting it and pressing the {} button. You can find more info about what else is supported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
section type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection"
```

or, if you have no namespace

```
section type="FacebookConfigurationSection"
```

I assume the line that you commented out didn't work either?

```
FacebookConfigurationSection config = (FacebookConfigurationSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings");
```

Comment: Changing the type gives the same error. Also, I assume I have to leave those setting as is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with your `<facebookSettings>` section try it in following format:

```
<facebookSettings>
    <add key="appId " value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="appSecret " value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
            ...
            ...
<facebookSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why your code does not work, but try the below, I've tried a sample with your web.config file and it does work

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection sec = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("facebookSettings");
Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection _config = (sec as Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection); 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
    _config.AppID = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
    _config.AppSecret = TextBox2.Text.ToString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text))
    _config.CanvasPage = TextBox3.Text.ToString();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text))
    _config.CanvasUrl = TextBox4.Text.ToString();

_config.CancelUrlPath = "";
config.Save();
```

Comment: I see now that my code is basically the same as your commented out line but if you debug step over the sec part and see if that has a value?